# How can Urbosa give you the power to call lightning if that power comes from her Divine Beast?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

In the cut scenes for Mipha, Daruk, and Revali it is made clear that each of their respective powers (healing, protection, upwards draft) is an ability unique to them (if not genetic as Daruk's offspring also have his ability of protection). When clearing the Divine Beast's their spirits transfer these gifts to you.  However, Urbosa's divine beast cut scenes - and the way the Gerudo speak of the divine beast - indicate that the divine beast can generate lightening - not Urbosa.

So, how can she give you the power of lightning when it was not something innate to her like Daruk's protection?

Answer (score 9):

Since the before-hand cut scenes only go into so much explanation about who the champions are or were, we can only get a few small pieces of information as to who they were as people.  It's been 100 years and most of their abilities are either legend or forgotten.

For Mipha, it seems that she just has a natural ability to heal.  That could mean that she was born to have healing ability out of the gate without any bloodline telling her she could, since her brother exhibits none of this.  Neither does her father.  We can take from that the idea the Mipha's is special to her.

Daruk obviously has his from a blood line.  His entire family has had this power and will always have this power.  His ancestor has it, so we know it travels down generations.  Daruk's parents and so forth must have had it too.  From that, we can take that it's a different source than Mipha's.

Revali doesn't seem to have a magical ability through blood line or special gift.  His seems more like he's honed and trained himself to have this special ability.  He brags about it like he's been able to master a technique that no other Rito has been able to emulate.  In this way, it seems his power is more a hidden talent or trained magic.

So, looking at what we know about Urbosa, a number of theories could be created.  Maybe her Divine Beast gave her the ability to unleash lightning so she could better control it.  Maybe she just naturally was able to contain the Divine Beast's power and can command it's lightning at will.  We know from previous Zelda games that Farore's element is wind.  Wind is close to lightning in most elemental cases, which also explains things like the Ether medallion in Link to the Past.  And since Farore's dragon is also present with lightning, we could infer that Urbosa is blessed by one of the goddesses, which is why she's not scared of the lightning.  She doesn't fear it, because Farore protects her (even if she doesn't know who Farore is, really).

Not enough to go on, but since I believe each champion has their own sources for their powers, Urbosa's could simply be another facet of power that we never see the source of, because it doesn't really matter for the context of the rest of the story.

Answer (score 3):

I think your confusing things slightly, my impression was that both the Divine Beast and Urbosa can summon lightning.

In the memory cut scene Urbosa wakes Zelda up by clicking her fingers and summoning a bolt of lightning, as all the other champions' memories also introduced their gifted ability somehow it's safe to say that this is Urbosa's power.
Just because the Divine Beast can do it too doesn't mean Urbosa can't. I'd also point out that the Divine Beasts lightning appeared to be purple (not 100% sure of that as I was busy trying to guide a sand seal and not get killed at the time), whereas that spawned by Urbosa's Fury is the more normal yellowy green like the game's natural lightning.

Edit:
See 2:32 of [this Youtube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j1f7lHUOM-0#t=2m32s), Naboris' lightning is purple and clearly generated by the Beast itself rather than coming from the sky.
Contrast that with 3:00 from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H_xxe79z4EY#t=3m00s) which shows Urbosa summoning a lightning bolt from the sky.

Comment: True. However, with all other cutscenes they explicitly state that the power you end up receiving was something particular to the champion (e.g. Revali masted his updraft, Daruk's protection was innate to him and his descendants, and Mipha was stated to have uncanny healing power). It is never stated that Urbosa *had* the ability to generate lightening. Nor is it explained when talking to her descendants. Rather we just see her snap and it appears, which - to me - appeared as her commanding it from the divine beast...

Comment: @SumNeuron When she grants Link the power, Link snaps his fingers just like her... so perhaps it *is* an innate ability that Urbosa had, and the Divine Beast simply amplified that power.

Comment: @MageXy possible, but after that cutscene it just happens during a charge attack. No snapping required with a spin attack.

Comment: @SumNeuron I've edited my answer with some links to youtube videos showing the two types of lightning.

Answer (score 1):

Well, Champion's Ballad DLC answered that question with a falshback scene that shows Urbosa using Urbosa's Fury before she became the Champion. Thus meaning that it's an innate ability of hers.

Answer (score 0):

In the Memory cutscene with Urbosa, Link, and Sleeping Zelda, She has the Thunder Helm right beside her. So her and her ancestors have had that thunder Helm from generation to generation. And somehow the Thunder Helm possesses the power of lightning. Which means that it could have been given the power of Lighting two different ways:

1. Farore, The Goddess of Wind, Created the thunder helm long ago and passed it down to the Gerudo.
   Or
2. It might have been a part of the Divine Beast Vah Naboris and was taken out of Vah Naboris.